# Get array's key recursively and create underscore separated string

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Right now i got an array which has some sort of information and i need to create a table from it. e.g.

```
Student{
      [Address]{
              [StreetAddress] =>"Some Street"
              [StreetName] => "Some Name"
      }
      [Marks1] => 100
      [Marks2] => 50
    }
```

Now I want to create database table like which contain the fields name as :

```
Student_Address_StreetAddress
Student_Address_StreetName
Student_Marks1
Student_Marks2
```

It should be recursive so from any depth of array it can create the string in my format.

Comment: You could at least have provided the array in PHP format.

Comment: DFS is quite easy to learn: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

Answer (score 19):

You can use the [RecursiveArrayIterator](http://php.net/recursivearrayiterator) and the [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://php.net/recursiveiteratoriterator) (to iterate over the array recursively) from the Standard PHP Library ([SPL](http://php.net/spl)) to make this job relatively painless.

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr));
$keys = array();
foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
    // Build long key name based on parent keys
    for ($i = $iterator->getDepth() - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
        $key = $iterator->getSubIterator($i)->key() . '_' . $key;
    }
    $keys[] = $key;
}
var_export($keys);
```

The above example outputs something like:

```
array (
  0 => 'Student_Address_StreetAddress',
  1 => 'Student_Address_StreetName',
  2 => 'Student_Marks1',
  3 => 'Student_Marks2',
)
```

Comment: How would you modify your code to get the field names in the right order, i.e. `'Student_Address_StreetAddress'` for example? Thanks

Answer (score 8):

(Working on it, here is the array to save the trouble):

```
$arr = array
(
    'Student' => array
    (
        'Address' => array
        (
            'StreetAddress' => 'Some Street',
            'StreetName' => 'Some Name',
        ),
        'Marks1' => '100',
        'Marks2' => '50',
    ),
);
```

---

Here it is, using a modified version of @polygenelubricants code:

```
function dfs($array, $parent = null)
{
    static $result = array();

    if (is_array($array) * count($array) > 0)
    {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value)
        {
            dfs($value, $parent . '_' . $key);
        }
    }

    else
    {
        $result[] = ltrim($parent, '_');
    }

    return $result;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r(dfs($arr));
echo '</pre>';
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Student_Address_StreetAddress
    [1] => Student_Address_StreetName
    [2] => Student_Marks1
    [3] => Student_Marks2
)
```

Comment: $arr = array
(
    'Student' => array
    (
        'Address' => array
        (
            'StreetAddress' => 'Some Street',
            'StreetName' => 'Some Name',
        ),
        'Marks1' => array(),
        'Marks2' => '50',
    ),
);
will response unwanted result

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe?

```
$schema = array(
    'Student' => array(
        'Address' => array(
            'StreetAddresss' => "Some Street",
            'StreetName' => "Some Name",
        ),
        'Marks1' => 100,
        'Marks2' => 50,
    ),
);

$result = array();

function walk($value, $key, $memo = "") {
    global $result;
    if(is_array($value)) {
        $memo .= $key . '_';
        array_walk($value, 'walk', $memo);
    } else {
        $result[] = $memo . $key;
    }
}

array_walk($schema, 'walk');

var_dump($result);
```

I know globals are bad, but can't think of anything better now.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this works:

```
<?php

$arr = array (
  'Student' => array (
     'Address' => array (
        'StreetAddress' => 'Some Street',
        'StreetName' => 'Some Name',
     ),
    'Marks1' => array(),
    'Marks2' => '50', 
  ),
);

$result = array();

function dfs($data, $prefix = "") {
   global $result;

   if (is_array($data) && !empty($data)) {
      foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        dfs($value, "{$prefix}_{$key}");
      }
   } else {
      $result[substr($prefix, 1)] = $data;
   }
}

dfs($arr);
var_dump($result);

?>
```

[This prints](http://www.ideone.com/nYToP):

```
array(4) {
  ["Student_Address_StreetAddress"] => string(11) "Some Street"
  ["Student_Address_StreetName"] => string(9) "Some Name"
  ["Student_Marks1"] => array(0) {}
  ["Student_Marks2"] => string(2) "50"
}
```

Comment: +1, I have something very similar to this (although I had no idea it was called DFS), the problem I'm facing is to return the array without using globals or references.

Comment: $arr = array ( 'Student' => array ( 'Address' => array ( 'StreetAddress' => 'Some Street', 'StreetName' => 'Some Name', ), 'Marks1' => array(), 'Marks2' => '50', ), ); will response unwanted result

Answer (score 0):

```
function getValues($dataArray,$strKey="")
{
    global $arrFinalValues;

    if(is_array($dataArray))
    {
        $currentKey = $strKey;
        foreach($dataArray as $key => $val)
        {
            if(is_array($val) && !empty($val))
            {   
                getValues($val,$currentKey.$key."_");
            }
            else if(!empty($val))
            {
                if(!empty($strKey))
                    $strTmpKey = $strKey.$key;
                else
                    $strTmpKey = $key;
                $arrFinalValues[$strTmpKey]=$val;
            }
        }
    }
}
```