# Save multidimensional array as "flat" with array keys and values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I got a multidimensional array with X number of .... dimensions?
Example of my array:

```
Array
(
[system] => Array
    (
        [step_x_y] => Array
            (
                [0] => Schnitt %1 von %2
                [1] => Trin %1 af %2
                [2] => Step %1 of %2
            )

        [type] => Array
            (
                [0] => Typ
                [1] => Type
                [2] => Type
            )

        [next_button] => Array
            (
                [0] => Aktualisieren
                [1] => Opdater
                [2] => Update
            )
[account.php] => Array
    (
        [h1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Kontoeinstellungen
                [1] => Konto Indstillinger
                [2] => Account Settings
            )

        [fields_required] => Array
            (
                [0] => Alle Felder, außer die Geschäftsinformation, müssen ausgefüllt werden
                [1] => Alle felter er obligatoriske, dog ikke virksomhedsinfo
                [2] => All fields required
            )
[mounting] => Array
    (
        [no] => Array
            (
                [text] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Keine
                        [1] => Ingen
                        [2] => Nothing
                    )

                [more_text] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Keine Befestigung
                        [1] => Ingen befæstelser
                        [2] => No mounting
                    )

            )

        [CFL] => Array
            (
                [text] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Frontflansch (CLF)
                        [1] => Front Flange
                        [2] => Front Flange
                    )

                [more_text] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Frontflansch zum Schweißen an dem Zylinderrohr
                        [1] => Front flange til påsvejsning på cylinder rør
                        [2] => Front Flange to be welded on cylinder tube
                    )

            ) ....
```

I'm trying to convert that array, into this "flat" format:
(# and the array keys that follows has to be included too)

```
# system > step_x_y
(DE) Schnitt %1 von %2
(DK) Trin %1 af %2
(EN) Step %1 of %2

# system > type
(DE) Typ
(DK) Type
(EN) Type

# system > next_button
(DE) Aktualisieren
(DK) Opdater
(EN) Update
```

I use this code, to output all values, one value per line:

```
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($merged_array));
foreach($it as $v) {
  echo $v, "<br>";    
}
```

A couple of problems:

- Not sure how to display the "row of keys" above the values.
- [0][1][2] has to replaced with country codes, 0=DE, 1=DK, 2=EN.

Something like this:

```
# system > step_x_y
(DE) Schnitt %1 von %2
(DK) Trin %1 af %2
(EN) Step %1 of %2

# system > type
(DE) Typ
(DK) Type
(EN) Type

# system > next_button
(DE) Aktualisieren
(DK) Opdater
(EN) Update
```

Hope one of you might be able to help me out :)

**UPDATE:**

I changed some of the code as suggested:

```
foreach ($it as $k => $v) {

  if($k == 0)
    $cc = '<br>(DE)';
  elseif($k == 1)
    $cc = '(DK)';
  elseif($k == 2)
    $cc = '(EN)';
  else
    $cc = '-';

  echo $cc, $v, "<br>";   
}
```

This is the output I recieve now:

```
(DE) Schnitt %1 von %2
(DK) Trin %1 af %2
(EN) Step %1 of %2

(DE) Typ
(DK) Type
(EN) Type

(DE) Aktualisieren
(DK) Opdater
(EN) Update
```

Just need to add "keys" above each "section" of values.
This to see where the text is located in the array (it's huge).

```
# system > step_x_y
(DE) Schnitt %1 von %2
(DK) Trin %1 af %2
(EN) Step %1 of %2

# system > type
(DE) Typ
(DK) Type
(EN) Type
```

Comment: `foreach ($it as $k =>  $v)`?

Comment: @Jeto I dont see see any difference in the output. I still get one value per row.

Comment: Well, `$k` should be the key that you need, unless I misunderstood.

Comment: My bad, it almost work now :) I get the key names in front of the values. Do you know how to post the names of all the keys "belonging" to the value? (Example: system > step_x_y ). Going to post a small update to my post with your code.

Comment: Oh I missed that part. Let me propose a solution then (give me a few mins).

Comment: Actually, found a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855211/php-recursive-iterator-parent-key-of-current-array-iteration. That should help.

Comment: that worked, thanks a lot. Please post an aswer, so I can accept :)

Comment: I actually posted an alternative solution below. If you like the other question's answer better then it should not be posted again here :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Recursive Iterator: Parent key of current array iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855211/php-recursive-iterator-parent-key-of-current-array-iteration)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate solution to the one in the related topic (see comments), here's a version without `RecursiveIterator*`, using a "simple" recursive function:

```
function getLeafsWithKeys(array $array, array $keys = []): array
{
  $result = [];
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $new_keys = is_numeric($key) ? $keys : array_merge($keys, [$key]);
    if (is_array($value)) {
      $result = array_merge([], ...[$result, getLeafsWithKeys($value, $new_keys)]);
    }
    else {
      $result[implode(' > ', $new_keys)][] = $value;
    }
  }
  return $result;
}
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/kWZUW**